# How can I resolve the issue where the formatNoMatches function in Select2 is not being called?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the Select2 library and I'm having trouble with the formatNoMatches option. I've declared the function and set the formatNoMatches option to it, but it never gets called. I've put a console.log statement inside the function to check if it's being executed, but it's not being printed. How can I get the formatNoMatches function to work with Select2?

This is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("Prima");
            
            var options = {
                data: [{ id: 1, title: 'ciao', text: 'pippo ciao' }, { id: 2, title: 'ciao', text: 'pippo ciao' }],
                formatNoMatches: function () {
                    console.log("Chiamata formatNoMatches");
                    
                    return "<a href='URL_DEL_LINK' target='_blank'>Nessun risultato trovato, clicca qui per ulteriori informazioni</a>";
                }
            };
            console.log("Dopo");
            $("#pippo").select2(options);
            console.log("Fine");
        });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <select class="form-control" id="pippo"></select>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you let us know why you think this is a valid option in select2?  (ideally with a link to the select2 documentation), There's no mention of it on https://select2.org/configuration/options-api nor does the text "formatNoMatches" appear in the source: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.js

Comment: How much did you want to change it?   You can do basic styling, eg `.select2-results__option.select2-results__message { font-style:italic; }` and/or it should be possible to change the `message` via options

Comment: And you can change the *text* (text only, no html) using language, eg: `$("#pippo").select2({ language: { noResults: function () { return "you failed" } }});`